# Windows Phone Phonecall with dtmf

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, dtmf

I know using phonecalltask we can make a call programmetically by filling the phonenumber field .

A sample code may be

```
 PhoneCallTask phn = new PhoneCallTask();
 phn.PhoneNumber = "9807689,657";
 phn.show ();
```

But my question is,is it possible to send dtmf right at the point when we are initiating calls ?

like in android and iphone we can send dtmf by dividing the number with ",". EX: 9876543,123

Is it also possible in windows phone? if possible is windows phone uses the same format to separate dtmf number or they use other tag other than "," ?

How to call programatically using p and w commands,and most predominantly  the dtmf sound must send automatically after call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did the test. Your code works, and the DTMF are played right after the callee answers the phone.

`p` and `w` are supported as well, looks like the implementation is conform to the [RFC 3601](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3601).

Comment: Thank you . I was testing it in emulator and emulator wasnt outputting any sound tone for the dtmf. Thats why i was confused weather dtmf tone is being sent or not . Will now test it on device. Thanks anyway.