# How can I programmatically press phone buttons (0-9, #, * ) when a particular number calls me?

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to write a phone app, which would automatically press some phone buttons (0-9, #, *) and then end the call when a particular number calls me. Ideally this works for windows phone 8.1. Is it possible? I can't find any API which I could use.

However, it would also work for me if a solution exists for Android. But I couldn't find a way to do it there either.

Any pointers to API documentation? Or apps which already do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such android API.  There's an API for generating it over the speaker, but none for sending it to the other side of the call.  THis is a security issue-  Android does not allow anyone to access call audio, in either direction.

This might work for windows phone: [Windows Phone Phonecall with dtmf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036243/windows-phone-phonecall-with-dtmf)

BTW, a good google term to use in your search is DTMF.  Its the industry name for the beep sound keys make.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I know of allowing you to do this would be to create your own Dialer as part of the platform (replacing or modifying InCallUI), I doubt that's what you're trying to do though?

If you are making a platform app, look into this code:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/services/Telecomm/src/com/android/server/telecom/Call.java#843